# Using a GUI to create an object graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, canvas, blazor

## In brief

I'm after suggestions for how best to write a .NET application that provides a design canvas that will allow a user to create an object graph.

## In more detail

Imagine the following .NET POCO class

```
public class BuildingBlock
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BuildingBlock? Child { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that someone ccould create an object graph in the following manner:

```
BuildingBlock start = new()
{
    Name = "One",
    Child = new()
    {
        Name = "Two",
        Child = new()
        {
            Name = "Three"
        }
    }
};
```

But, my user is not a programmer.  They need to create this, but want a nice UI where they can drag 'n' drop objects, or right-click on the screen and pick "new block" *etc*.  For those familiar with it, it would be similar to the design canvass in the Power Virtual Agents (PVA), or the designer in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

I'd of course need to validate the model - so the `Name` property may have rules around it, such as it must be no longer than 5 characters, and can't contain numbers (simple for a Regex test).  I may have a rule that the object graph can only be 12 objects "deep".

This program could save a serialized version of the object graph (xml, json etc).  So also, it could read in this serialized file and paint a representation on the canvas for further editing.

Obviously my actual class would be far more complex than the one shown, but you hopefully get the gist.

What would be the best way to approach this, from a .NET perspective?  I'm not sure which libraries etc I should look at.  This could be a desktop app, or web/blazor.

Comment: `BuildingBlock? Child` can only make a List, not a Tree.

Comment: If you want a nice clean GUI, I recommend creating components using inline .svg, which reads almost the same as html markup, and can easily be parameterized in Blazor the same way: inline .svg is Blazor's most underrated asset IMO.  The drag and drop will be done in Javascript using JS Interop.

I can explain how to do these things, but it will be from scratch.  It's worth the effort, in my opinion, but it will be a fairly major undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Look up a tutorial on WinForms `TreeView` control which supports drag and drop, and context menus. What you will learn will be translatable to other UIs. As Henk mentioned, you need a collection of child nodes `List<BuildingBlock> Children`, not just a single `BuildingBlock? Child`.

If you want to record this in a relational database, each node will need to record a reference to its parent, e.g. `Guid? ParentId`.

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant to the tags asp.net & blazor.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The question specifies it could be a desktop app or Blazor.